# PHP / mySQL - in_array and Get Result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like below and that array refers to another data on my db,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
)
```

how do I want to select value no 1, and get the most top value from table that has `value=1`?

I use `in_array(1,$array)` but it does not output anything. Below are my coding;

```
$sql = " Select * FROM table_name WHERE staff_id='".$_SESSION['staff_id']."' ORDER BY table_name DESC ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$leave_id= array();
while($row_permohonan=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_permohonan))
{  
    $leave_available = $row_permohonan['leave'];
    $leave_id[] = $row_permohonan['leave_id'];
} mysqli_free_result($result_permohonan);

//echo '<pre>'; print_r($leave_id); echo '</pre>';  
if(in_array(1,$leave_id)){
    echo $leave_available .'/'.$row['total_leave'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed `$result`.

```
$sql = " Select * FROM table_name WHERE staff_id='".$_SESSION['staff_id']."' ORDER BY table_name DESC ";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$leave_id= array();
while($row_permohonan=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) //Here
{  
    $leave_available = $row_permohonan['leave'];
    $leave_id[] = $row_permohonan['leave_id'];
} mysqli_free_result($result); //And here
```

Comment: Then check `print_r($leave_id)` outside of while loop and then see what you are getting.
And also check what FragBis said.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code is not clear. You are using:

```
echo $leave_available.'/'.$row['total_leave'];
```

Where "$row" is not set anywhere into your code. If you have put on top of your code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On"); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

PHP would break with a fatal error if you are executing the code exactly as you gave it. But I assume that you set it somewhere else into your code.

2nd: You should return the data you want into your MySQL query. If you just want to know if there is at least 1 row into your database having leave_id=1  and staff_id=$_SESSION['staff_id'], then add this condition in your SQL query:

```
$sql = "Select COUNT(*) AS nbrows FROM table_name WHERE staff_id='".$_SESSION['staff_id']."' AND leave_id=1 ORDER BY column_name DESC ";
```

And then: you have to use "ORDER BY" statement with a **column name** and not the table name.

Using "in_array": as you are matching "1", I would recommend you to add "true" as 3rd parameter of this function (force using "strict comparison" in case sensitive and type matching):

```
in_array(1, $array, true)
```

Then, you'll also have to cast your $leave_id result:

```
$leave_id[] = (int)...
```

(int) cast the string value to integer (as PHP results from database are almost strings)